# Heroku run Docker image with port parameter

Tags: heroku, docker, dockerfile

When I push an existing Docker image to Heroku, Heroku provides a `$PORT` environment variable. How can I pass this property to the Heroku run instance?

On `localhost` this would work:

```
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-ui
docker run -p 80:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

On Heroku I should do:

```
docker run -p $PORT:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I think Heroku expects your web-app will listen on $PORT rather than you choosing the port it will listen on.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Comment: Yep, this is correct. My main question is how to define this $PORT variable in my dockerfile?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to run this same thing currently. It does seem like you shouldn't need to do anything, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: I didn't find the soluation at the time of posting this. Sorry.

Comment: does anyone please help me im working on these and don't know how to deploy locally running swagger images on Heroku and how to access it ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old now, but still I will write my answer here if it can be of some help to others.

I have spring-boot App along with swagger-ui Dockerized and deployed on Heroku.

This is my application.yml looks like:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
  servlet:
   contextPath: /my-app

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: '/swagger-ui.html'
```

Below is my DockerFile configuration.

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as maven_build
WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn clean package -Dmaven.main.skip -Dmaven.test.skip && rm -r target

COPY src ./src
RUN mvn package spring-boot:repackage

########run stage########
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache bash


COPY --from=maven_build /app/target/springapp-1.1.1.jar ./

#run the app
# 256m was necessary for me, as I am using free version so Heroku was giving me memory quota limit exception therefore, I restricted the limit to 256m
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Xmx256m"
ENTRYPOINT  ["java","${JAVA_OPTS}", "-jar","-Dserver.port=${PORT}", "springapp-1.1.1.jar"]
```

The commands I used to create the heroku app:

```
heroku create
heroku stack:set container
```

The commands I used to build image and deploy:

```
docker build -t app-image .
heroku container:push web
heroku container:release web
```

Finally make sure on Heroku Dashboard the dyno information looks like this:

```
web java \$\{JAVA_OPTS\} -jar -Dserver.port\=\$\{PORT\} springapp-1.1.1.jar
```

After all these steps, I was able to access the swagger-ui via

[https://testapp.herokuapp.com/my-app/swagger-ui.html](http://my-app)

Answer (score -1):

Your Docker container is required to listen to HTTP traffic in the port specified by Heroku.

Looking at the Dockerfile in the [Github repo for swaggerapi/swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), it *looks* like it already supports the PORT environment variable: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/be72c292cae62bcaf743adc6236707962bc60bad/Dockerfile#L13

So maybe you don't really need to do anything?
It looks like this image would just work, if shipped to Heroku as a web app.